# User ID of a Blog Owner in WordPress MultiSite

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working on creating a function that will take a `$blog_id` and return the corresponding `$user_id` of the user who owns/created the blog in a multi site network.

```
public function SelectOwnerUserIdFromBlogId( $blog_id ) { ... }
```

I have been reviewing the database and the closest thing I can find is looking at the wp_usermeta table and filtering on capabilities but this feels too hackish. Any better idea?

```
SELECT user_id as UserId,
    IF(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(meta_key, '_', 2), '_', -1) = 'capabilities', 1, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(meta_key, '_', 2), '_', -1)) as BlogId
FROM wp_usermeta
WHERE meta_key like '%_capabilities'
    AND meta_value like '%administrator%'
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured out the query. Just replace the blog_id in the WHERE condition to get the desired user ID.

```
SELECT meta_value as UserId
FROM wp_blogs b
JOIN wp_sitemeta sm
    ON sm.site_id = b.site_id and sm.meta_key = 'admin_user_id'
WHERE b.blog_id = 2
```

Comment: Sadly this won't do it. Sitemeta table stores meta about the network, not blogs in it, except `blog_count`. `admin_user_id` meta field will always be the same for every blog in a network.

Answer (score 0):

This is how i am doing it:

Hook into the [wpmu_new_blog](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wpmu_new_blog) action which will be fired when a new site is created.

In your function for this, do the following:

```
add_site_option( 'site_author', $user_id );
```

Site authors will now be added to the site options.

Answer (score 0):

Can't speak to anything earlier, but as of the current version (4.9.7), you can use network options to achieve this.

```
add_action('wpmu_new_blog', 'record_site_operator', 10, 2);

function record_site_operator($blog_id, $user_id) {
    update_network_option(NULL, 'site_operator_'.$site_id, $user);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Just do this:

```
 // replace 2 with ID of site you want to use.
 $target_id = 2;
 $alluser = get_users( 
                array( 'blog_id' => $target_id,
                    'fields' => array( 'ID' ),
                     'exclude'  => array( 1), // excluding 1 because it's super admin of network
                 )
            );
```

$alluser have the ID of all users who are a member of site ID 2.